# Auto Redial Option To Call A Specific Number In Cordova App

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am new to PhoneGap and have been researching if auto redial option can be implemented. There is no any specific option to redial a call if error occurs (concluded from my research).  Is it possible to redial a number until it is picked in cordova app?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

so you calling function or method call in after end of call your in every 1 seconds using

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  /// call your calling function here so after cal cut redial again.
}, 100);
```

Comment: But how can we know that the call has been aborted or canceled? This option only allows to call the calling function. But the call has to stop if it has been picked. Can you suggest any available plugin to do this?

Comment: in your code you have to find it out in which section your call state end and after end you have to call you calling state.  http://rickluna.com/wp/2012/02/making-a-phone-call-from-within-phonegap-in-android-and-ios/

Comment: Can you help me out finding this CALL STATE END. This is where I have been stuck. I'm just a beginner hence do not have much knowledge. It would be of great help.